# How to fix this MySql select problem?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

```
$_GET['id'] = $id1;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE id = '$id1'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   //some code
}
```

Why isn't this code working? It doesn't obey the `id='$id2'` bit. It gets everything from table example.

How can I fix it?

---

<sup>The example table contains `id,text,time rows`. The file name is `example.php?id=1`.</sup>

Comment: What makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: `It doesn't obey the id='$id2' bit. ` there is no $id2 in your code

Comment: Note: SQL injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Dude, you're doing it wrong. You're not assigning $id1 to something.

Answer (score 7):

shouldn't that be `$id1 = $GET['id']` ?

But you should watch out because your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack, someone could query a crafted url like `example.php?'; delete from example;`

Comment: Actually in this case they couldn't, but it's worth getting into the habit of sanitising inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Is `$_GET['id'] = $id1;` supposted to be `$id1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);`?

Answer (score 0):

will this work for you ? Its been a long time since i used php the last time...

```
$id1 = $_GET['id']; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE id = '$id1'"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    //some code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Did you mean `$id1 = $_GET['id'];`?
- Where did you protect yourself from SQL injection?
- Why is all your code on one line?
- Please don't write signatures/thanks in your posts.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is a numeric field on your table, try removing quotes:

```
"select * from example where id = $id1"
```

And of course:

```
$GET['id'] = $id1;
```

Should be:

```
$id1 = $GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `$id1 = $_GET['id'];` instead of `$_GET['id'] = $id1;`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$id1 = $_GET['1'];
$id1 = (int)$id1;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE id = $id1 ");
```

Try Doesn't use *

Try call real names of **poles like tablename.user_name,tablename.user_login**